# Finding a column/variable in a dataframe to pass to a function - R

Tags: r, function, variables, vector, dataframe

I am taking data that exists in a dataframe and turning particular variables to vectors of characters.   This is done by 'id' and the results are stored in a list.

This shows what's happening:

```
###sample data
id<-rep(1:5, each=4)
fruits<-c("orange", "apple", "banana", "lemon", "kiwi")
shapes<-c("triangle", "square", "circle", "rhombus")
dat<-as.data.frame(id)
dat$fruits<-sample(fruits,20,replace=T)
dat$shapes<-sample(shapes,20,replace=T)
dat$anotherid<-rep(1:2, each=10)

dat
```

This sample data contains two possible variables for id-ing the observations, and two possible variables that we may wish to turn into a vector sequence.  It will looks something like this (obviously each execution of the code will return different results because 'fruits' and 'shapes' are selected at random:

```
   id fruits   shapes anotherid
1   1   kiwi triangle         1
2   1 banana  rhombus         1
3   1  lemon  rhombus         1
4   1  lemon  rhombus         1
5   2 orange  rhombus         1
6   2  lemon triangle         1
7   2  apple triangle         1
8   2 banana   circle         1
9   3  apple   circle         1
10  3   kiwi   square         1
11  3  apple  rhombus         2
12  3 orange  rhombus         2
13  4 orange triangle         2
14  4 orange  rhombus         2
15  4  apple triangle         2
16  4  lemon triangle         2
17  5 banana   square         2
18  5 orange  rhombus         2
19  5 orange triangle         2
20  5 orange  rhombus         2
```

This is the script that I have come up with that does the transformation.  Say, we wish to turn the variable 'fruits' into a character vector, and do it by 'id':

```
n<-which( colnames(dat)=="id")
n1<-which( colnames(dat)=="fruits")
z<-split(dat[n1],dat[n], drop=TRUE) 
L = lapply(z, function(x) as.character(unlist(x)))
L
```

It looks like this:

```
$`1`
[1] "kiwi"   "banana" "lemon"  "lemon" 

$`2`
[1] "orange" "lemon"  "apple"  "banana"

$`3`
[1] "apple"  "kiwi"   "apple"  "orange"

$`4`
[1] "orange" "orange" "apple"  "lemon" 

$`5`
[1] "banana" "orange" "orange" "orange"
```

So, I am trying to turn this into a function.  If I do the following, then it works fine for the example above:

```
myfunction<-function(dat,id,fruits){
  n<-which( colnames(dat)=="id" )
  n1<-which( colnames(dat)=="fruits" )
  z<-split(dat[n1],dat[n], drop=TRUE) 
  L = lapply(z, function(x) as.character(unlist(x))) 
  return(L)
}

myfunction(dat,id,fruits)
```

However, I am trying to make the function generic, so that I could call any 'id' variable and any other variable to be turned into a vector.   Below, I've used the arguments 'col1' to refer to the id variable and 'col2' to refer to the variable for vectorizing.   I have removed the "" from the function above around col1 and col2. (It also doesn't work with them, because obviously it is looking for a variable named 'col1' & 'col2').

Say, I wanted to use 'anotherid' as the id variable and 'shapes' as the vectorizing id.  This is not working as I am doing something wrong with how I am trying to find the columnn number in the dataframe in the function:

```
myfunction<-function(dat,col1,col2){
  n<-which( colnames(dat)==col1 )
  n1<-which( colnames(dat)==col2 )
  z<-split(dat[n1],dat[n], drop=TRUE) 
  L = lapply(z, function(x) as.character(unlist(x))) 
  return(L)
} 

myfunction(dat,anotherid,shapes)
```

The following error message (just for completeness):

```
Error in which(colnames(dat) == col1) : object 'anotherid' not found
```

Any help appreciated.  Obviously, with this simple example I could just change the code to the appropriate variable names - but I want to make this generic for a dataframe with 100s of variables, and to use this script many times - thus a generic function is best.

Comment: Use `set.seed()` to make your `sample` reproducible. That would help others identify whether they have actually successfully addressed your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here's the issue - in your first function,

```
myfunction<-function(dat,id,fruits){
  n<-which( colnames(dat)=="id" )
  n1<-which( colnames(dat)=="fruits" )
  z<-split(dat[n1],dat[n], drop=TRUE) 
  L = lapply(z, function(x) as.character(unlist(x))) 
  return(L)
}
```

the arguments `id` and `fruits` aren't actually used in the function body, so you could just as easily call `myfunction(dat)` and get the same results:

```
$`1`
[1] "apple"  "kiwi"   "orange" "apple" 

$`2`
[1] "orange" "banana" "lemon"  "kiwi"  

$`3`
[1] "kiwi"  "kiwi"  "apple" "kiwi" 

$`4`
[1] "kiwi"   "apple"  "kiwi"   "banana"

$`5`
[1] "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange"
```

This is because `dat` is the only argument being used, and since there is an object also named `dat` in the global environment, internally the function is actually doing `myfunction(dat=dat)`. This wouldn't work if you had used `Dat` or anything else instead of `dat` as your function argument. 
Now, when you revised the function to

```
myfunction<-function(dat,col1,col2){
  n<-which( colnames(dat)==col1 )
  n1<-which( colnames(dat)==col2 )
  z<-split(dat[n1],dat[n], drop=TRUE) 
  L = lapply(z, function(x) as.character(unlist(x))) 
  return(L)
}
```

and called `myfunction(dat,anotherid,shapes)`, you got the error `object 'anotherid' not found` because you passed it without quotes, so the function tried to do

```
myfunction(dat=dat, col1=anotherid,col2=shapes)
```

and unless you have an object called `anotherid` in your global environment (which is a valid character name contained in the column names of `dat`), you will get an error because the function is literally trying to use an object named `anotherid` for the value of `col1`. The same would have happened for `col2` if `col1` hadn't caused an error and halted the function. 
So what you can do is just pass in quoted names to your second function (I believe, as a minimal fix), but you might consider adding in some defensive code as well to check for errors.

```
myFun <- function(Dat,col1=NULL,col2=NULL){
  ##
  cNames <- names(Dat)
  if(is.null(col1)){
    if(!("id" %in% cNames)){
      col1 <- cNames[1]
    } else {
      col1 <- "id"
    }
  }
  ##
  if(is.null(col2)){
    if(!("fruits" %in% cNames)){
      col2 <- cNames[2]
    } else {
      col2 <- "fruits"
    }
  }
  ## Dat fixed from dat[,col2] and dat[,col1] per your comment below
  z <- split(
    Dat[,col2], 
    Dat[,col1],
    drop=TRUE
  )
  ##
  L <- lapply(
    z, 
    function(x){
      as.character(unlist(x))
    }
  )
  ##
  return(L)
}
##
myFun(Dat=dat)
$`1`
[1] "apple"  "kiwi"   "orange" "apple" 

$`2`
[1] "orange" "banana" "lemon"  "kiwi"  

$`3`
[1] "kiwi"  "kiwi"  "apple" "kiwi" 

$`4`
[1] "kiwi"   "apple"  "kiwi"   "banana"

$`5`
[1] "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange"
##
> myFun(Dat=dat,col1="anotherid")
$`1`
 [1] "apple"  "kiwi"   "orange" "apple"  "orange" "banana" "lemon"  "kiwi"   "kiwi"   "kiwi"  

$`2`
 [1] "apple"  "kiwi"   "kiwi"   "apple"  "kiwi"   "banana" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange"
```

In this version, I used default values for `col1` and `col2` so you can just call `myFun(Dat=dat)`, or you can manually specify `col1` and `col2`. Either way, you are required to specify `Dat`. This is not an ideally robust function because I just wrote it hastily, but it does make use of default argument values, which is a useful feature to add to your functions. Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to name function arguments the same thing as the objects you intend to use them on, but you are certainly free to do this if you choose.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The points you make are well-taken.    Just a note about the function you wrote.   Scanning it, I presume that the lines....  z <- split(
    dat[,col2],
    dat[,col1],
    drop=TRUE     .....   here, 'dat' should actually be 'Dat'.  (i.e. the name of the dataframe).    Sorry for introducing confusion by using dat initially.

Comment: Yes! Good catch - this is exactly the sort of thing I was taking about. If `dat` did not exist in my global environment, this would have produced an error.